# How to get time in GMT from milliseconds

Tags: android

Need to show time in GMT...but it showing in UTC

```
long m=Long.parseLong("1444588200000");

  Date localTime = new Date(m);

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),
          Locale.getDefault());
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
String time = date.format(localTime);
    infoip.setText(" "+time);
```

Comment: it working after changes in Settings in phone

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
final Date currentTime = new Date(); 

final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");

// Give it to me in GMT time. 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("GMT time: " + sdf.format(currentTime));
```

Comment: Its giving result like GMT time: 08/10/2015 09:58:06.002

Comment: GMT & UTC display same time value. What you exactly expecting?

Comment: now time showing like oct 11,2015 6:30 PM
but In Gmt time like oct 12,2015 12:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

Try like this hope work.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// setting the timezone for which you want
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
cal.setTimeInMillis();

// The date is in your home timezone 
Date date = cal.getTime();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.GMT);
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
// Then we do the conversion to convert the date you provided in milliseconds to the GMT timezone
String result = sdf.parse(date);
```